# plural or singular for a single-entry set

Tags: grammatical-number

There is a term "a set of generalized coordinates" in physics that is used to describe a system. But for some simple systems, the set contains just one generalized coordinate. Can we say, for example, "we define {x} as a set of generalized coordinates"?

Comment: I can't see any other way to say it.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

"We define {x} as a set consisting of one generalized coordinate."

Comment: This formulation would lead me to expect that there is a larger set of generalized coordinates, form which just one $x$ has been chosen for membership in your set.  So I agree with @Colin Fine that the formulation in the question is better.